# How to increase integer even click button

Tags: android

i want to increase my integer. but i don't know to fix it
Even i am using this code, my picture more brightness with int +10 from before.

```
try {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            Bitmap bMap = mPhoto;
            int a=0;
            image.setImageBitmap(SetBrightness(bMap,20+a));
            a = a + 10;
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Can you help me?

**solution**

```
 try {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            Bitmap bMap = mPhoto;
            mPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(SetBrightness(bMap,20));
            image.setImageBitmap(mPhoto);

} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Just with code above....
When i click, this code increase by itself :)

Comment: consider a should be global variable

Comment: Are you increasing you are integer on button click what else you are doing? Can elaborate your question?

Comment: make "a" a global int and in click function do a += 10....

Answer (score 0):

in your button in click set this

```
a += 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onClickListener` for imageView. And in onClick method you can increase your integer value.

```
  imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           //increase integer value

                   a = a + 10;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please notice that your variable **a** should be a **global** variable. so that it doesn't set to zero every time when you try to increase brightness. 
And for the way you can increase brightness by value 10, on clicking a button is:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          //your code//
                       a = a + 10;


        }
```